# Service Temporarily Unavailable after installing a module

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento-connect, nginx

I'm running NGinx 1.6.2 with Magento 1.9.1.1 - just wanted to install SMTP Pro Email via the Connect/Mag Downloader webinterface and it got till:

> Checking dependencies of packages
>   Starting to download ASchroder_SMTPPro-2.0.6.tgz ...
>   ...done: 32,911 bytes

Then I checked the frontpage after a couple of minutes because I thought there was a problem and I get now everywhere:

> Service Temporarily Unavailable
>   The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

There are no logfiles written (/var/log/ is empty) and I don't see anything in the NGinx error - just a 200 in the NGinx access log.

I checked all directories for leftovers from the SMTP extension but nothing has actually been written so far.
I emptied the cache in /var/cache but nothing changes either.

My question: What happens before the download of an extension finished or is being extracted?
Maybe via that way I could figure out how to get my shop back?
Or does anybody know where to digg?

Comment: check "maintance.flag" file is present in root folder. If yes delete that file and refersh again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

check "`maintance.flag`" file is present in `root` folder.

If yes delete that file and refresh again.

refer this [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102777/service-temporarily-unavailable-magento)

Comment: True, that was the villain - quite easy if one checks at the right place ;) Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

Check system log, Remove cache and check for any maintenance flag as well. 
Try opening Magento in the private browser window as well.

Answer (score 0):

In lots of cases, after installing a new extension and recompiling Magento 2 code, you need to set file and folder permissions again.

After running these commands through SSH:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

You then need to reset the file permissions and reset file ownership by running these commands through SSH:

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                   // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                   // 755 permission for directory

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;               // 777 permission for var folder

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R 10000:1004 .

chmod u+x bin/magento

That should fix the "Service Temporarily Unavailable" issues.

Sometimes you might need to run this command more than once:

chown -R 10000:1004 .